# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P=\begin{pmatrix} 1-\alpha & \alpha & 0\\
0 & 1-\beta & \beta \\
\gamma & 0 & 1-\gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$ where $0<\alpha,\beta,\gamma<1$.

So, $P-\lambda=
\begin{pmatrix} 1-\alpha-\lambda & \alpha & 0\\
0 & 1-\beta-\lambda & \beta \\
\gamma & 0 & 1-\gamma-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}.$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
0 = \det(P-\lambda) = & (1-\alpha) \cdot 
\begin{vmatrix} 1-\beta-\lambda & \beta \\
0 & 1-\gamma-\lambda \end{vmatrix}
-\alpha \cdot
\begin{vmatrix} 0 & \beta \\
\gamma & 0 \end{vmatrix} \\
= & (1-\alpha-\lambda) \cdot 
(1-\beta-\lambda) \cdot (1-\gamma-\lambda)
-\alpha \cdot
(0 - \beta \gamma ) \\
= & (1-\alpha-\lambda)(1-\beta-\lambda)(1-\gamma-\lambda)
+\alpha \beta \gamma \\
= & 1-\alpha-\beta-\gamma+\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma + (2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma-\alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\alpha\gamma-3)\lambda \\
& + (3-\alpha-\beta-\gamma)\lambda^2 -\lambda^3 \\
= & (\lambda -1)(1-\alpha-\beta-\gamma+\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma + (\alpha+\beta+\gamma-2)\lambda + \lambda^2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

From here I was thinking to use the quadratic formula on the remaining quadratic but with the fact that I don't know what $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are equivalent to I thought it was a dead end.

When $\lambda=1$, then $$P-\lambda=\begin{pmatrix} -\alpha & \alpha & 0\\
0 & -\beta & \beta \\
\gamma & 0 & -\gamma 
\end{pmatrix}.$$ We can observe that the eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: What is the sum of each row? Is it constant? Do you know what this tells you?

Comment: The sum of each row is 1. I'm not sure what it tells me

Comment: Consider a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ such that the sum of both rows equals a number $k$, in other words, $a_{11}+a_{12}=k=a_{21}+a_{22}$. Multiply this matrix by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. What can you conclude? Can you generalize your conclusion?

Comment: That $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ can be anything

Comment: What's your definition of eigenvalue?

Comment: The values of $\lambda$ for which $\det(P-\lambda)=0$

Comment: I've never seen that definition. Anyway, it's equivalent to there being a non-null vector $v$ such that $Pv=\lambda v$ because $Pv=\lambda v$ with $v$ not zero is equivalent to $(P-\lambda I)v=\bf 0$ which means that $P-\lambda I$ is not invertible and so its determinant is null. Therefore $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$ if, and only if, $Pv=\lambda v$ for some non-null vector $v$. Can you apply this fact to my second comment here?

Comment: Why not use the quadratic formula? You will get two eigenvalues in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ in the end, in addition to the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh But the result is ugly right?

Comment: a little messy but when you simplify its not that bad

Comment: I was able to simplify $b^2-4ac=(\gamma-\alpha-\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta$. Do you see how to make that part nicer?

Comment: why do you want it to be nicer? that seems fine...

Comment: No reason. I thought it could turn into something that you can actually take the square root of